# Theano Scan and Repeat

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, pymc3

In Theano, there is an option to use the repeat function `T.repeat(A,B)` and supply a pair of vectors, such that each element of `A[i]` is repeated `B[i]` times.

Unfortunately, this operation has no defined gradient (it throws a notimplemented exception) which is a problem, as I'm trying to use this with `Pymc3`'s gradient based samplers.

I think I can address this using the `scan` function and calling repeat recursively for each element of the two vectors, however my code isn't working, probably because I'm calling `scan` incorrectly. Can anyone help me understand why the below code isn't working?

```
A = T.dvector('A')
B = T.ivector('B')
A.tag.test_value = np.array(np.random.rand(2), dtype = "float32")
B.tag.test_value = np.array(np.random.rand(2), dtype = "int32")
th.config.compute_test_value = 'warn'

results, updates = th.scan(fn = lambda prior_result, A, B: A.repeat(B),
                          sequences = [A, B],
                          outputs_info = T.constant([1,4,4,4]))

b = th.function(inputs=[A,B], outputs=results.flatten())
b([1],[4])
```

I'd expect this to return [1,1,1,1] but instead it returns the below error.

```
    395     except AttributeError:
    396         return _wrapit(a, 'repeat', repeats, axis)
--> 397     return repeat(repeats, axis)
    398 
    399 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (1,) (4,)
```

I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/960) on the Pymc3 github to see if this is something that should be fixed more permanently, but I figure its a good opportunity to learn more about Theano for me anyway, and if I can resolve the problem maybe I can contribute back to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I see here two things:

1. Bad ordering in lambda expression: it should be A, B, prior_result (now B is treated as outputs_info)
2. shape of A.repeat(B) is different from shape of prior_result (at this stage of compilation)

quick fix: just remove outputs_info from scan's arguments (and prior_result from lambda) and you will get [1,1,1,1].